# Kivy installation error on OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, kivy

I am trying to instal Kivy by following the instructions on [this page](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-macosx.html).

I already installed Cython and Pygame, yet when I try to install Kivy from the command line the following error appears before the code stops executing:

```
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-   
2.7/kivy/graphics/texture.o -o 
/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/graphics/texture.so -  
F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/
Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -framework OpenGL 
-arch x86_64 -lm
```

Any idea what might be causing this? I can post more details of the error if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: That's not an error, that's just the command line used to build `texture.so`.

Comment: Thanks - do you have any idea why the installation would stop at this point?

Comment: The page you linked doesn't show these steps - so what are you actually doing?

Comment: My guess is that whatever you're doing isn't "installation", but "building"—e.g., maybe you typed `make`—and it stops at this point because it's finished successfully? Without knowing exactly what you typed, it's hard to offer more than vague guesses…

Comment: I followed  the instructions on the page I linked to up to and including the steps in "Installing the dev version". After the build stops  I am unable to import kivy in my python IDE ("no module named Kivy"). I'm very new to this so I'm guessing there is something simple that I am missing.